# Automatically derive traits implementation for Arc

Tags: rust, traits, reference-counting

I have a trait and a `struct` implementing it. The `struct` wrapped in `Arc` can call trait's method, but the `Arc` itself does not implement it:

```
use std::sync::Arc;

trait Foo{
    fn bar(&self);
}

struct A;

impl Foo for A{ 
    fn bar(&self){ }
}

fn test<A: Foo>(arc_a: Arc<A>){
    let foo_obj: & dyn Foo = &arc_a; //the trait bound `std::sync::Arc<A>: Foo` is not satisfied
}
```

The following code works just fine:

```
use std::sync::Arc;

trait Foo{
    fn bar(&self);
}

struct A;

impl Foo for A{ 
    fn bar(&self){ }
}

impl<A> Foo for Arc<A> //Manually implemented
where
    A: Foo
{ 
    fn bar(&self){ self.bar() }
}

fn test<A: Foo>(arc_a: Arc<A>){
    let foo_obj: & dyn Foo = &arc_a;
}
```

Is there a way to derive such trait's implementation automatically?

Comment: Do you mean to take a reference to `arc_a` or did you mean to take a reference to the `A` behind it? `let foo_obj: &dyn Foo = &*arc_a;` should work. But if you meant the other thing, yeah you have to implement it for `Arc` specifically if that's the behavior you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to implement them manually. While your manual implementation of `Foo for Arc<A>` seems completely trivial, the important part is "hidden" in `self.bar()`, where an automatic deref takes place from `self: &Arc<A>` to `&A`. Remember that your implementation `Foo for Arc<A>` could be in fact be something completely different; in the real world, we usually simply want the "deref impl", though.

In your first example

```
fn test<A: Foo>(arc_a: Arc<A>){
    let foo_obj: &dyn Foo = &arc_a;
}
```

This will compile if you do `= &*arc_a`, as the `*arc_a` derefs from `Arc<A>` to `A` and `&*arc_a` then is a `&dyn Foo`.

In your second example, you provide a manual implementation `for Arc<A>`

```
impl<A> Foo for Arc<A> where A: Foo { 
    fn bar(&self){ self.bar() }
}
```

Here, the deref - which was explicit above - is now implicit in `self.bar()`. This saves you from having manually deref but the impl could be completely different. For example:

```
impl Foo for A{ 
    fn bar(&self){ println!("This is fine") }
}

impl<A> Foo for Arc<A>
where
    A: Foo
{ 
    fn bar(&self) { panic!() }
}

fn test<A: Foo>(arc_a: Arc<A>){
    let foo_obj: & dyn Foo = &arc_a;
    foo_obj.bar()
}

fn main() {
    test(Arc::new(A))
}
```

The above program will panic, as `foo_obj` uses the `impl for Arc<A>`. If you change the line in `test` to `= &*arc_a`, the `impl for A` is used and the program will print "This is fine".

If you need only trivial impls of `Foo` for the common smart pointers, you can do it via a macro:

```
macro_rules! deref_impl {
    ($($sig:tt)+) => {
        impl $($sig)+ {
            fn bar(&self) {
                (**self).bar()
            }
        }
    };
}
deref_impl!(<'a, N> Foo for &'a N where N: Foo + ?Sized);
deref_impl!(<'a, N> Foo for &'a mut N where N: Foo + ?Sized);
deref_impl!(<N> Foo for Box<N> where N: Foo + ?Sized);
deref_impl!(<N> Foo for std::rc::Rc<N> where N: Foo + ?Sized);
deref_impl!(<N> Foo for std::sync::Arc<N> where N: Foo + ?Sized);
```

Comment: An issue with a manual implementation is that default methods *must* be implemented for Arc too, otherwise Arc will use the default implementation even when the underlying type provides its own.

Comment: And there doesn't seem to be a way to enforce that all default methods are implemented.